# Gulp-imagemin не сжимает изображения в формате webp

Tags: javascript, gulp

Собственно проблема возникает только при сжатии webp, с другими форматами проблем не возникает.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема? И как её решить?

Код gulpfile.js

```js
// VARIABLES & PATHS

let preprocessor = 'sass', // Preprocessor (sass, scss, less, styl)
  fileswatch = 'html,htm,txt,json,md,woff2', // List of files extensions for watching & hard reload (comma separated)
  imageswatch = 'jpg,jpeg,png,webp,svg', // List of images extensions for watching & compression (comma separated)
  baseDir = 'app', // Base directory path without «/» at the end
  online = true; // If «false» - Browsersync will work offline without internet connection

let paths = {

  scripts: {
    src: [
      'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
      'app/js/jquery.lazy.min.js',
      'app/js/slick.min.js',
      // 'app/js/jquery.mask.min.js',
      'app/js/jquery.fancybox.min.js',
      baseDir + '/js/app.js' // app.js. Always at the end
    ],
    dest: baseDir + '/js',
  },

  styles: {
    src: baseDir + '/' + preprocessor + '/main.*',
    dest: baseDir + '/css',
  },

  images: {
    src: baseDir + '/images/src/**/*',
    dest: baseDir + '/images/dest',
  },

  deploy: {
    hostname: 'username@yousite.com', // Deploy hostname
    destination: 'yousite/public_html/', // Deploy destination
    include: [ /* '*.htaccess' */ ], // Included files to deploy
    exclude: ['**/Thumbs.db', '**/*.DS_Store'], // Excluded files from deploy
  },

  cssOutputName: 'app.min.css',
  jsOutputName: 'app.min.js',

}

// LOGIC

const {
  src,
  dest,
  parallel,
  series,
  watch
} = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass');
const scss = require('gulp-sass');
const less = require('gulp-less');
const styl = require('gulp-stylus');
const cleancss = require('gulp-clean-css');
const concat = require('gulp-concat');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const uglify = require('gulp-uglify-es').default;
const autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
const imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
const newer = require('gulp-newer');
const rsync = require('gulp-rsync');
const del = require('del');

function browsersync() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: baseDir + '/'
    },
    notify: false,
    online: online
  })
}

function scripts() {
  return src(paths.scripts.src)
    .pipe(concat(paths.jsOutputName))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(dest(paths.scripts.dest))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
}

function styles() {
  return src(paths.styles.src)
    .pipe(eval(preprocessor)())
    .pipe(concat(paths.cssOutputName))
    .pipe(autoprefixer({
      overrideBrowserslist: ['last 10 versions'],
      grid: true
    }))
    .pipe(cleancss({
      level: {
        1: {
          specialComments: 0
        }
      },
      /* format: 'beautify' */
    }))
    .pipe(dest(paths.styles.dest))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream())
}

function images() {
  return src(paths.images.src)
    .pipe(newer(paths.images.dest))
    .pipe(imagemin())
    .pipe(dest(paths.images.dest))
}

function cleanimg() {
  return del('' + paths.images.dest + '/**/*', {
    force: true
  })
}

function deploy() {
  return src(baseDir + '/')
    .pipe(rsync({
      root: baseDir + '/',
      hostname: paths.deploy.hostname,
      destination: paths.deploy.destination,
      include: paths.deploy.include,
      exclude: paths.deploy.exclude,
      recursive: true,
      archive: true,
      silent: false,
      compress: true
    }))
}

function startwatch() {
  watch(baseDir + '/' + preprocessor + '/**/*', {
    usePolling: true
  }, styles);
  watch(baseDir + '/images/src/**/*.{' + imageswatch + '}', {
    usePolling: true
  }, images);
  watch(baseDir + '/**/*.{' + fileswatch + '}', {
    usePolling: true
  }).on('change', browserSync.reload);
  watch([baseDir + '/js/**/*.js', '!' + paths.scripts.dest + '/*.min.js'], {
    usePolling: true
  }, scripts);
}

exports.browsersync = browsersync;
exports.assets = series(cleanimg, styles, scripts, images);
exports.styles = styles;
exports.scripts = scripts;
exports.images = images;
exports.cleanimg = cleanimg;
exports.deploy = deploy;
exports.default = parallel(images, styles, scripts, browsersync, startwatch);
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/imagemin-webp

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как его подключить в мою сборку? Эту сборку делал не я. Я пытаюсь подключить в функцию images(), но не получается.